# iOS: What is the best way to display a lot of text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, character, uitextview

I have a lot of text in a UITextView, but because of this the App slows down and text don't even show up and the the App crashes. Is there an effective way to show a lot of text in a UITextView? Is there some alternative way to show all of this text? Any tips or suggestions is appreciated. The crash is just from memory leak.

The text has over 17000 characters.

Comment: Define "a lot of text". Provide details about the crash.

Comment: wow, how much text do you have ?? It seems crazy to have the app have a memory crash for a lot of text. What is the crash you're seeing ?

Comment: 17000 characters should not make the device crash. You should monitor your app in Instruments and see what is leaking

Comment: If the crash is from a memory leak, fix the memory leak.